# Assigning an array of custom type from a function return

Tags: c#, dll, vb6

I've constructed a C# DLL which uses a custom object (called `PropertyObject`) to store some data. I can pass this through to VB6 and use it fine. However, I have a function which returns an array of type `PropertyObject`, and I cannot for the life of me assign this returned array to a `Dim`med array. The code is fairly simple, as shown below:

```vb
Dim PObject As New PCom
Dim PropObj() As PropertyObject

PropObj = PObject.GetPropertyObjects()
```

Whenever I call this, I get `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`. despite the fact that `GetPropertyObjects` returns a **PropertyObject()** array. Is there something missing, or do I need something crazy like an extension to support custom array types?

Comment: If you press F2 in VB6, exactly what does it show for the type of `PCom.GetPropertyObjects`?

Comment: Then it is not an array, it's a single object being returned. What's on the C# side?

Comment: Both the interface to the method and the method itself both return `PropertyObject[]`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I've just created a new C# COM-enabled dll with your two classes, `PCom` and `PropertyObject`, both with `[ComVisible(true)]` and `[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]` (quick and dirty). VB6 sees the method as `Function GetPropertyObjects() As PropertyObject()` and it assigns to an array no problem. Please post your interface and class definitions with attributes.

Answer (score 0):

In VB6, the "native array" type system and the "COM object" type system *really* don't play well together. You sometimes have to resort to trickery to force the VB6 runtime to do what you want.

Try assigning the method return value to an intermediate variant variable before attempting to reinterpret it as an array, e.g.

```
Dim PObject As New PCom
Dim PropVar As Variant
Dim PropObj() As PropertyObject

PropVar = PObject.GetPropertyObjects()
PropObj = PropVar
```

Even if this makes no difference, you will at least be able to debug the exact data type of the value. :-)

Also, try removing the `()` from the end of the method call, it may make a difference to how VB6 interprets the data.

Comment: Your description filled me with hope :-) Unfortunately, I still get  a straight `Type Mismatch` error, before the array can be assigned to the Variant. No extra information is shown.

Comment: I've never had to do this kind of a trick in VB6. "Native array" for VB6 *is* the COM SAFEARRAY.

Comment: Hmmm. Could you post your C# interface and coclass definitions?

Comment: @GSerg: True, but the way that .NET COM Interop forces you to declare SAFEARRAYs is not quite compatible with the way that VB6 expects them to be declared. You can only get 100% compatibility using raw IDL and C++. Plus VB6 is really bad at array handling anyway.

Comment: Just as I was copying the info you wanted, I realised that the class I'm returning had no coclass definition. I rebuilt the DLL and now get a totally different error: `Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from it's clients`, which I guess I'll need to point into a different question. Thanks for the help. Now, how do I close this question...?

Comment: @Skulmuk: You're welcome. :-) You can either click the "close" link below the question, or you can add your own answer explaining the solution, then mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: PS: I guess the Automation error is probably because you still had the VB6 app or IDE in memory when you rebuilt the C# code. Close everything down and try again. Bear in mind that by changing the C# code you are breaking binary compatibility in the COM type library, with all the consequences that implies.